# Opening sub-projects from within the Master Project

Tags: ms-project, process

(Not using Project Server)
I find a frequent need to open sub-projects in a new window and looking for an easy way to open that project from within the master project instead of having to go through the typical File/Open and file search.

Any shortcuts?

Rachel.

Answer (score 2):

No direct method that I know of.  If the inserted subprojects are linked to the master, you can copy the file path from the Inserted task Information dialog (Advanced tab).  Paste into file explorer.  But, I'm not sure that is any more efficient. :-)

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the feedback.